# fontawesome icon not showing inside html table <th>

Tags: html

I am trying to add an icon inside one of the headers of my html table. This is my code:

```
<div id="dialog_box">
    <table id="req_header" border="2">
       <tr>
          <th><i class="fa-solid fa-list-check"></i></th>
          <th>Table</th>
          <th>QtrID</th>
          <th>Requested by</th>
          <th>Reason</th>
       </tr>
   </table><br>
   <button id="delete_qtrid">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Strangely the icon isn't showing after executing the code. I have also included my kit code:

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/03d58ba9c7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

inside my `<head></head>` section in my html file. Where am I going wrong? Please help me.

**EDIT:** Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Check the console to see if the js file is being loaded properly. If yes, inspect the icon and check whether the fontawesome css is being loaded

Comment: The console is completely empty!

Comment: alright, click on the icon and see what css is being loaded

Comment: it's showing `i.fa-solid.fa-list-check 0x0` when I hover over the `html` icon

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of your page along with the console tab. Just attach it with the question

Comment: I've posted. Please have a look

Comment: Your fa library styles are not loading. You can see that the `font-family` for the icon is still Lucia something instead of font-awesome